# Lightning: Stop page refreshing WHEN Enter key is pressed

Tags: lightning-aura-components, slds, lightninginput

I am using the `ui:inputtext` for lightning component. When the user hit enters the page refreshes. Is there anyway to stop it from doing that.

Cmp

```
<aura:component controller="MovieController">

    <aura:registerevent name="searchfilter" type="c:searchEvent"/>
    <aura:attribute name="movie" type="Movies__c"
                     default="{'sobjectType' : 'Movies__c',
                             'Name': '',
                             'Director__c': '',
                             'Genres__c': '',
                             'Duration__c': 0,
                             'Year__c': 0,
                             'Content_Rating__C': '',
                              'Plot__c': ''}"/>
    <div class="SearchBox" >
 <fieldset class="slds-box slds-theme--default slds-container--full">
    <form class="slds-form--stacked">

         <div class="slds-form-element slds-is-required">
          <div class="slds-form-element__control" style="text-align: center">
             <div calss="searchinput" style="padding-left: 150px; padding-right: 150px; padding-bottom: 20px; min-width: 200px;">
        <ui:inputText aura:id="iName"  value="{!v.movie.Name}" label="Search"
                      class="slds-input"   
                      labelClass="slds-form-element__label"
                      keyup="{!c.checkKey}"/>
              </div>
               <ui:button label="Search"  press="{!c.SearchMovie}"/>
             </div>
        </div>        

        <!--ui:button label="Clear"  press="{!c.clearFields}"/-->

    </form>
    </fieldset> 
  </div>
</aura:component>
```

controller

```
SearchMovie : function(component, event, helper) {

        helper.getMoviesfiltered(component);   
 },
    checkKey : function(component, event, helper){
     if(event.getParams().keyCode == 13){
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log("enter was pressed");
         helper.getMoviesfiltered(component);
      }
 },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ui:inputText element fires off a COMPONENT event, which basically hides the native DOM event. There's a parameter you're expected to use (apparently) to get to the base event. Here's a self-contained, fully functional version:

```
<aura:application >
    <form>
        <ui:inputText keydown="{!c.handleKeyDown}" label="Input" />
    </form>
</aura:application>
```

---

```
({
    handleKeyDown: function(component, event, helper) {
        var domEvent = event.getParam("domEvent");
        if(domEvent.keyCode === 13) {
            domEvent.preventDefault();
            console.log('Enter key was pressed. Cancelling form submission.');
        }
    }
})
```

---

Alternatively, you can handle the form submission itself:

```
<aura:application >
    <form onsubmit="{!c.preventDefault}">
        <ui:inputText label="Input" />
    </form>
</aura:application>
```

---

```
({
    preventDefault: function(component, event, helper) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

When you are using form, pressing `enter` when in input, it will automatically submit the form and so browser refreshes. Even use of `event.preventDefault()` will not stop it.

***edited based on recommendation from @sfdcfox in comments***

For resolving the issue, change `form` to `div` tag :- `<form class="slds-form--stacked">` in your code to `<div class="slds-form--stacked">`

OR

---

**ADDED**

If you want the form to be present, prevent default on form submit as following:

```
<form class="slds-form--stacked" onsubmit="{!c.formSubmitted}">
    -- logic --
</form>
```

JS:

```
formSubmitted : function(component, event, helper){
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: this seems to be working, is there a way to wire the press enter to a search button? in other words when the user hit enter key can call the method `SearchMovie ` ?

Comment: You are already doing that `if(event.getParams().keyCode == 13){` - all the code inside this if block will execute when enter is pressed

Comment: Added solution in answer

Comment: I disagree with this solution. The problem is more subtle, and there is a way to prevent form submission. Removal of the form is not required.

Comment: Yes @sfdcfox, so I added `if not needed` and gave other solution

Comment: I think we dont actually need form in lightning context as the form submit has no scope in lightning (also no viewstate). And thats the reason, I said it, Do you think form has some functionality in lightning? @sfdcfox

Comment: @salesforce-sas Older trailheads (like [this](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lex_dev_lc_basics/lex_dev_lc_basics_forms)) include a `form`. Also, you do need *some* outer wrapper (usually a `div`), so you can't remove the element entirely (slds-form_stacked, etc is needed for visual layout). A better version of this answer would be to suggest changing `form` to `div` instead, as modern SLDS demonstrates.

Comment: I was just writing about it - div is better than form in lightning! @sfdcfox

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to stop the standard submission of the form, and call your method directly from a button click or pressing enter in the input box. Correct?

If so, you can stop the form's submit event by changing your form tag to include the following:

```
<form class="slds-form--stacked" onSubmit="return false">
```

Comment: did not work, still refreshes the page

Comment: @NickKahn In Lightning, you have to call a controller method: `onsubmit="{!c.preventDefault}"` and `preventDefault: function(component, event, helper) { event.preventDefault(); }`